# select all check boxes in a window

Tags: java

I'm new with in java, adn I have some check boxes and a button on a window, I want when I click on this button to select all check boxes in the window.

In C# I was using this :

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls) {
    if ((c) is CheckBox) {
        c.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

**How can I do this in Java ?**

this is the code I tried

```
for (Component c : this.getComponents()) {
   if(c instanceof JCheckBox)
       c.setSelected(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way is to simply have all the checkboxes in a collection (a `List<JCheckBox>`, for example), and iterate on the list:

```
private List<JCheckBox> checkboxesToCheckWhenButtonIsPressed = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();

public MyPanel() {
    // ... 
    // create the checkboxes, and fill the list of checkboxes
    // create the button
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (JCheckBox checkBox : checkboxesToCheckWhenButtonIsPressed) {
                checkbox.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempted code won't compile as it needs to be a `JCheckBox` cast to make so that the `setSelected` method is available. Also the loop won't reach any nested containers. To achieve this you could use a recursive method to make the `for` loop call, first passing in the `ContentPane` of the `JFrame`:

```
void checkAllCheckBoxes(Container container) {

   for (Component c: container.getComponents()) {
      if (c instanceof Container) {
         checkAllCheckBoxes((Container)c);
      } 

      if (c instanceof JCheckBox) {
         ((JCheckBox) c).setSelected(true);
      } 
   }
}
```